# EF Core FromSql for same model but with different queries and extra columns

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have C# class `Operation`

```
public class Operation 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF Core [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) I want to use it for multiple queries. All good then I write select my self. But the problem I am facing, is that there are stored procedures that I cannot change. And these stored procedures does not return all columns needed for my class.

For example `SP_1` returns `Id`, `Name` and `Code`. `SP_2` returns `Id`, `Name` and `Description`.

Is there any way that I can set these properties to some default or dummy values? Or just ignore these optional properties, but map to class when they are being returned from database?

Answer (score 0):

For your queries that are not a table model for you, different objects will be a better quality solution.

> These are DTO models

```
class obj1
{
Id
Name
Code
}

class obj2
{
Id
Name
Description
}
```

The contents of the procedures will necessarily change.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know this is negative point of EF/EF Core. FromSql not only requires generic, it also requires that response you are getting from query is 1 on 1 (model/table in database) so it can map it properly.

For stuff like that, you can use ADO.NET (maybe even Dapper, but I have never used it before).

EDIT: You could do it with EF/EF Core, but it will be ugly. You would need to create new models for each response you want to get via FromSql method and use that models for new tables in your database. But don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not quite an EF Core answer, I've had a lot of joy with this kind of thing using Dapper (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper).

It does mean going back to using System.Data.SqlClient or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but it allows you to run a custom SQL Query and map the results back to an object. So in your example

```
using Dapper;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("")){
    connection.Open();

    IEnumerable<Operation> operations = connection.Query<Operation>("exec sp_1",
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map your data to a DTO (Data Transfer Object).

This DTO can be customized depending on your needs

You can map any field you want to output from the entity to the special DTO

This mapping can be done manually or by an automapper